# WF result OR property from one activity as input to next activity in designer

Tags: workflow-foundation

I'm using the designer to string together some `CodeActivity` based activities. Using the property window where you can enter VB expressions, I'm not sure how to reference the previous activity.

There are two things I'd like.

1. Get the result of the previous activity and pass it to an in Argument property in the designer.
2. Possibly read an `InArgument` of the previous activity. So if I set an in argument to the name of a file, I'd like to be able to read the filename. I can change them to inout parameters if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class derived from `CodeActivity<string>`

Comment: No, that's what I already have. In the designer I have the code activity connected to another activity. How do I reference the result of one from the other in the designer?

Comment: In designer, when you select the activity derived from CodeActivty<string>, you will find one parameter called Result. Add a variable and assign Result to it. That variable can be put to InArgument of next activity

Comment: @HM Chan, how to assign the Result to a Variable?